# ERROR: ldd outputLine: "libicui18n.so.56 => not found"

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ld, ldd

I want to use [linuxdeployqt](https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt) tool, but this command:
`./linuxdeployqt-continuous-x86_64.AppImage /home/user/QtProjects/build-VPSTest-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_GCC_64bit-Release/VPSTest`

Outputs this:

```
Not using FHS-like mode
app-binary: "/home/user/QtProjects/build-VPSTest-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_GCC_64bit-Release/VPSTest"
appDirPath: "/home/user/QtProjects/build-VPSTest-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_GCC_64bit-Release"
relativeBinPath: "VPSTest"
ERROR: ldd outputLine: "libicui18n.so.56 => not found"
ERROR: for binary: "/home/user/QtProjects/build-VPSTest-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_GCC_64bit-Release/lib//libQt5Core.so.5"
ERROR: Please ensure that all libraries can be found by ldd. Aborting.
```

Next I did this:
`ldd libQt5Core.so.5`

This command outputs:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007fff7e5c1000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff552c43000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff552a29000)
libicui18n.so.56 => not found
libicuuc.so.56 => not found
libicudata.so.56 => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff552823000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff552621000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff552419000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff552109000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff551d87000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff551a7f000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff551867000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff55149d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000562d67831000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007ff55122f000)
```

Next I opened `/home/user/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/lib/`, this is location of the `libQt5Core.so.5`, and of course I found `libicui18n.so.56`, `libicuuc.so.56` and `libicudata.so.56`.

So, how can I fix this issue and create deployment bundle using linuxdeployqt tool?

Comment: Maybe adding `/home/user/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/lib/` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will help?

Comment: You can usually have multiple versions of `libicu` : Install "libicu56" . But you will of course have to edit your question to include OS name, version, arch ... if you want a link to libicu56.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [this solution](https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt/issues/220#issuecomment-360516490):

```
PATH=/home/user/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```